# White space to right when I have a slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

So I am trying to have a slider menu with content underneath. Well, I have the menu all done, and the slider works, but there is just a tiny white space to the right that makes it scroll. This is no big deal really, but it does bug me. If you guys could help me fix this, that would be much appreciated.

```js
$('span.nav-btn').click(function() {


  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 1000) {

      $('ul.nav').removeAttr('style');
    }
  })
});
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
.nav {
  background-color: #E74C3C;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
}
.nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  margin: 0;
  padding;
  0;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 100px;
}
.content {
  /*
 width: 100%;*/
  background-color: #333;
}
.contentArea {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .nav {
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
  }
  .nav > li {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav > li > a {
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 150px;
  }
  .nav-btn {
    display: block;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 200px;
  }
  .nav-btn:before {
    content: "Menu";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <!-- Begin Navigation -->
  <nav>
    <span class="nav-btn"></span>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#home">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#projects">PROJECTS</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#videos">VIDEOS</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- End Navigation -->

  <!-- Begin Content -->
  <div class="content">

    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
        <img src="http://www.placecage.com/c/460/460" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
        <img src="http://www.placecage.com/g/460/460" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
        <img src="http://www.placecage.com/460/460" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
      </div>
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
    </div>

    <!-- Begin Content Area -->
    <div class="contentArea">
      <p>hi</p>
    </div>
    <!-- End Content Area -->
  </div>
  <!-- End Content -->
</div>
```

I put the slider css and main css in different files because I want to keep it nice and clean.

Also if you want to see the site, you can visit it here. jumpymotionpictures.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you add the following to your CSS:

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This will simple stop the overflow on the x axis by making it hidden...

Therefore you will not be able to scroll, and not be able to see the white space!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons for this.

1. Your `contentArea` has a fixed width of 1000 pixels, try changing it to something else, for example 100%. This will help on smaller screens.
2. There is a container with a class `text`. Its `box-sizing` defaults to `content-box` on most browsers which excludes padding from width calculation. When the container's width is set to 100% and it has padding, the padding will be added on top of that 100%.
   To include padding to the container's width, add this to the `text` class styles: `box-sizing: border-box;`

```js
$('span.nav-btn').click(function() {


  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 1000) {

      $('ul.nav').removeAttr('style');
    }
  })
});
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
.nav {
  background-color: #E74C3C;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
}
.nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  margin: 0;
  padding;
  0;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 100px;
}
.content {
  /*
 width: 100%;*/
  background-color: #333;
}
.contentArea {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .nav {
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
  }
  .nav > li {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav > li > a {
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 150px;
  }
  .nav-btn {
    display: block;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 200px;
  }
  .nav-btn:before {
    content: "Menu";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <!-- Begin Navigation -->
  <nav>
    <span class="nav-btn"></span>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#home">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#projects">PROJECTS</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#videos">VIDEOS</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- End Navigation -->

  <!-- Begin Content -->
  <div class="content">

    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
        <img src="http://www.placecage.com/c/460/460" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
        <img src="http://www.placecage.com/g/460/460" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
        <img src="http://www.placecage.com/460/460" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
      </div>
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
    </div>

    <!-- Begin Content Area -->
    <div class="contentArea">
      <p>hi</p>
    </div>
    <!-- End Content Area -->
  </div>
  <!-- End Content -->
</div>
```